# Is it possible to direct users to a certain post based on a password entered on the home page?

Tags: posts, password

I'd like to be able to have a workflow that works like so:

1. Create a post and assign it a password
2. Have a single-field form on the home page
3. User enters password on home page, and is sent to the corresponding post

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Does this mean that the post is not viewable until the password is entered? Or is it more like a keyword thing?

Comment: I'd like it to not be viewable until the password is entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tom's help, here's what I ended up with. This uses the built in functionality for password-protecting a post, so a visitor only has to enter a password on the home page, then they are taken to the post and are able to directly view the post content without re-entering the password.

On home page:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="password" name="passwordfield">
    <input type="hidden" name="homepagepassword" value="1">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In `functions.php` (of course this could be converted to a plugin):

```
if(isset($_POST['homepagepassword'])){

    global $wpdb;

    $post_password = $_POST['passwordfield'];
    $post_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_password = %d", $post_password) );
    $q = new WP_Query( 'p=$post_id' );
    if($q->have_posts()){
        while($q->have_posts()){
            $q->the_post();
            wp_redirect(get_permalink());
            die();
        }
    } else {
        // oh dear, there isnt a post with this 'password', put a redirect to a fallback here
        wp_redirect('http://www.google.com');
        die();
    }
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but you'll need to hold the details of how a password maps to a post.

So:

- store mappings somewhere, easiest as a hash/key-value pair (password->post_id)
- get password from field
- determine post_id, and construct the URL
- use [wp_redirect()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) to redirect the user.

Comment: Do you have any insight on how to accomplish the first thing (storing the mappings)?

Comment: @tnorthcutt The easiest way of doing this is to use a custom field - you'll probably want to add an index to the postmeta table for the meta_value field.

Answer (score 3):

On the homepage:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="password" name="passwordfield">
    <input type="hidden" name="homepagepassword" value="1">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Place in functions.php *( create the file if it doesnt already exist and add `<?php` at the top)* or in a plugin file:

```
function doPasswordStuff(){
    if(isset($_POST['homepagepassword'])){
        $pass = $_POST['passwordfield'];
        $q = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'password_value', 'meta_value' => $pass));
        if($q->have_posts()){
            while($q->have_posts()){
                $q->the_post();
                wp_redirect(get_permalink());
                die();
            }
        } else {
            // oh dear, there isnt a post with this 'password', put a redirect to a fallback here
            wp_redirect('http://www.google.com');
            die();
        }
        wp_reset_query();
    }
}
add_action('init','doPasswordStuff');
```

Add a custom field to your post with the key/name `password_value` and the value being your password.

If you want to skip this step and use the password Wordpress uses to lock the post directly, you will need to use `$wpdb` and an SQL query, and to hash the password your checking prior.

**edit:** I've updated this to use the 'init' hook, you can put the code in a plugin file instead of functions.php if you want this to be theme independent. ( Although you will still need to put the form markup somewhere ).

Comment: Thanks, Tom. I was able to get this working using the built in password functionality for posts that WordPress provides thanks to your code and suggestion. I'll add an answer with the code I used and accept it to show the full solution, but you get the bounty!

Answer (score 1):

I would do that with a plugin instead. The plugin could still share the password with the post and set the cookie appropriately so the page wouldn't be accessible w/o entering the password.

A plugin because to have a manual mapping, the lookup which password belongs to which post would be really expensive without such a mapping. Not useful in a central location like the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

Are the passwords you create for each post going to be unique? If not, how will you be able to identify which post a user is looking for?

Assuming you are keeping each password unique, I would store the password as post-meta. You could create a [custom meta box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) which allows for entry/storage of the password.

Then, when a user enters the password on the home page:

1. Sanitize the user input (Duh!)
2. Run a custom query using [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters). In this query you can use the meta_query argument to search for posts that have the password entered by the user.
3. Load and display the required post.